# How to catch str_get_html (Simple HTML Dom) error if fails to retrieve when larger than MAX_FILE_SIZE

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I have an issue with a part of my script that retrieves emails from AWS SES S2 Bucket and when getting the body of the email it looks for Base64 inline images and converts it to an image file and then I upload that image to an S3 bucket and then change the `src` of the image to that URL.

The issue is that sometimes an email will contain an inline image and/or files that is larger than my `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in my `simple_html_dom.php` file. Of course, I could just increase the size, but ultimately I have to put a cap as to how large of an email I am willing to parse.

I have messed around trying to do a `try` and `catch` which does not seem to work.
I have also tried doing

```
$message = str_get_html($body);
if ($message) {
    // process email
} else {
    // Email to big skip images.
}
```

but that has no chance to even check for an error since the script will break at `$message = str_get_html($body);`

Is there a method to catch an error on `str_get_html()`?

**What I have done**

In my effort to combat this issue I have done the following

```
$size = mb_strlen($body_of_email, '8bit');
if ($size < 25000000) {
    $message = str_get_html($string);
}
```

The `$message` is stored in a MySQL table which is how I am retrieving it.

The only concern I have is that I am not sure the potential for a `false positive` could occur using `mb_strlen` on `$message` from MySQL and the possibility of getting a different size using `mb_strlenm` after getting the string with `str_get_html($message)` which is simple HTML dom. I have tested both ways and they do produce the same number.

Is there anything I need to be aware of for potential issues that can arise?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `the script will break at $message = str_get_html($body);`? Looking at the source for simple html dom it returns `false` if `MAX_FILE_SIZE` is breached so maybe something else at play here.

Comment: @cOle2 The script stops at that point and will not continue. If I increase the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` to something larger then it will process the string and continue.

Comment: How can I catch the `false` with  `MAX_FILE_SIZE`